# PHP sql using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert

I am trying to learn how to use PDO so my forms aren't SQL injected.
I am confused on how to code the execute function for my insert.

This is my code:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=x;dbname=x;charset=utf8', 'x', 'x');
if ( !$db )
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$mail = $_POST['mail'];

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM ucm_signup WHERE email =? ") or exit(mysql_error());
$stmt->bindValue(1, $mail, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$num_rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if($num_rows == 0) 
{ 
//if there are no duplicates...insert

$sql = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO ucm_signup company, address1, address2, city, province, zip, fname, lname, email, phone, session, iama, buyfrom, group1, ipaddress )
VALUES ( '$_POST[company]','$_POST[address1]','$_POST[address2]','$_POST[city]', '$_POST[province]','$_POST[zip]','$_POST[fname]','$_POST[lname]','$_POST[mail]', '$_POST[phone]','$_POST[session]','$_POST[iama]','$_POST[buyfrom]','$_POST[group1]', '$ipaddress')");
$sql->execute(array(':company' => I AM LOST))
}
```

Am I even close on the INSERT ? Thank you

Comment: Nope, you aren't. Why don't you use the same **prepared statement** principle you used for SELECT?

Comment: Put your `$_POST[fields]` in the `execute(array(...))`, associate them to :placeholder names, which you put in the INSERT statement in place of the quoted literal variables.

Comment: If you want to learn PDO, read the tutorials and follow them to a `T`. [`Here, read this`](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)

Comment: `VALUES(:foo)` then `execute(array(":foo" => "bar"))` where `bar` is `$_POST['bar']` in your case..

Comment: @Fred-ii- That is what I was reading to do this :/

Comment: Where do `$_POST[...]` come into play on that page? @DDDD Here's what's on that page to INSERT `<?php
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO table(field1,field2,field3,field4,field5) VALUES(:field1,:field2,:field3,:field4,:field5)");
$stmt->execute(array(':field1' => $field1, ':field2' => $field2, ':field3' => $field3, ':field4' => $field4, ':field5' => $field5));
$affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount();`

Comment: @Fred-ii- My signup.php page POSTs to this page the values.

Comment: `$field1` is to be read between the lines. You need to do `$field1=$_POST['company'];` as an example. You don't do the INSERT that way for your VALUES. @DDDD

Comment: You're welcome @DDDD See the answers given below, cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of fetching rows and checking against zero you should check for `rowCount()`. Your first query is correct, but the second one needs to be changed, you will need to use prepared statment here as well and binding your parameter, you could use for example

```
$num_rows = $stmt->rowCount();
if($num_rows == 0) 
{ 
    $sql = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO ucm_signup company, address1, address2, city, province, zip, fname, lname, email, phone, session, iama, buyfrom, group1, ipaddress )
    VALUES (:company,:address1,:address2, .....)");
    $sql->bindParam(':company',$_POST[company],PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sql->bindParam(':address1',$_POST[address1],PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sql->bindParam(':address2',$_POST[address2],PDO::PARAM_STR);
    //and so on
    $sql->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No! Do not do this! always bind your parameters. By directly placing $_POST['company'] in, someone could inject SQL code by submitting it through post. Here's a better solution:

```
$sql = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO ucm_signup company, address1, address2, city, province, zip, fname, lname, email, phone, session, iama, buyfrom, group1, ipaddress
VALUES ( :company, :address1, :address2,:city, :province, :zip, :fname, :lname, :mail, :phone, :session, :iama, :buyfrom, :group1, :ipaddress)");
$sql->bindValue(":company", $_POST['company']);
$sql->bindValue(":address1", $_POST['address1']);
//...
$sql->bindValue(":ipaddress", $ipaddress);
$sql->execute()
}
```

The reason being, PDO sends the prepared statement and parameters separately. By doing this, it automatically prevents against SQL injection. A user could put ANYTHING into those variables, and it still would not inject SQL because of how PDO utilizes parameterized statements.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it right with the SELECT query. Why arent you doing the same with the INSERT?

I did not debug your code, so it may not be just copy and paste:

```
// first of all count($num_rows)!
if(count($num_rows) == 0) 
{ 
    // you forgot "()" in column names and ":" in the binds On column values
    $sql = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO ucm_signup (column, another_column) VALUES (:value1, :value2)");
    $sql->execute(
        array(
            "value1" => $_POST['value1'],
            "value2" => $_POST['value2'],
        )
    );
}
```

Other than that is worth noticing a couple of things: PDO is like a first step. It doesnt do a lot of things that sophisticated database layers do. Even though you're preventing injection you should not use $_POST directly in the bind. It still lacks validation. If you're learning, it is a good start. But for something that would resemble code for production I recommend you take a look at some abstraction layer like [Doctrine DBAL](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/dbal.html%E2%80%8E). I am not talking about the ORM. The DBAL is a thin layer on top of PDO.

Answer (score 1):

This one would be more readable and easy to understand.

```
$ipaddress = $_SERVER ['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$email = $_POST ['mail'];
$stmt = $db->prepare ( "SELECT * FROM ucm_signup WHERE email =:email " );
$stmt->bindParam(":email", $mail);
$stmt->execute ();

if ($stmt->rowCount()==0) {
    // if there are no duplicates...insert

    $sql = $db->prepare ( "INSERT INTO ucm_signup(company, address1, address2, city, province, zip, fname, lname, email, phone, session, iama, buyfrom, group1, ipaddress)
        VALUES (:company,:address1,:address2,:city,:province,:zip,:fname,:lname,:email,:phone,:session,:iama,:buyfrom,:group1,:ipaddress)" );
    $sql->bindParam(":company", $_POST['company']);
    $sql->bindParam(":address1", $_POST['address1']);
    $sql->bindParam(":city", $_POST['city']);
    $sql->bindParam(":province", $_POST['province']);
    $sql->bindParam(":zip", $_POST['zip']);
    $sql->bindParam(":fname", $_POST['fname']);
    $sql->bindParam(":lname", $_POST['lname']);
    $sql->bindParam(":email", $_POST['email']);
    $sql->bindParam(":phone", $_POST['phone']);
    $sql->bindParam(":session", $_POST['session']);
    $sql->bindParam(":imea", $_POST['imea']);
    $sql->bindParam(":buyfrom", $_POST['buyfrom']);
    $sql->bindParam(":imea", $_POST['imea']);
    $sql->bindParam(":group1", $_POST['group1']);
    $sql->bindParam(":ipaddress", $_POST['ipaddress']);

    $sql->execute ();
    if($sql->rowCount()==1){
        //successfully inserted
    }else{
        //oops, some error occured.
    }
}
```